# Vue.js application with two different authentication strategies

Tags: vue.js, ldap, auth0

I have a request to build an Vue.JS application that will support two different authentication strategies. For external users application will use Auth0 while for internal employees we should use LDAP. My question is if it is possible to have both strategies in one Vue.JS application or I should rather build two separate application and try to somehow share the code between them.

Comment: it is possible to have both auth systems in one application, so you don't have to worry.

Comment: @ivandez so how can I decide which login screen show when not logged user tries to access "restricted" area?

Comment: In an application I worked, I showed the same login form, and according to whether the user has role A or role B, the request went to different routes, in your case a route with AUTH or LDPA authentication, this It's the way that I would do it

Comment: You can show the same login screen, given the submitted username you should be able to check if it exists and whether the corresponding user is an internal user or not (ie. your backend could expose an api user/isInternal that returns a boolean - but no user data), then you would invoke the proper authentication system.